# Error running rails server: can you guess what's wrong? How can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cloned a RoR project and tried to run it. I did install bundle and get everything ok. After that I ran 'rails server' and get this message. Is there something broken somewhere? Should I reinstall something? Thanks

```
$ rails server
/home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3.rb:11:in `require': /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:84: invalid multibyte escape: /[\x80-\xFF]/ (SyntaxError)
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/jck/www/Movie-Catalogue/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/jck/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/pull/23) in the aws-s3 gem. There is a demonstrated (but unmerged) fix in the ticket.